# How to eliminate extra fields in Class constructor via Dict or Json document

Tags: python, json

Let's say i Have a simple class with many fields

```
Class Myclass:
  def _init__(self, **fields)
     self.a = ""
     self.b = ""
     ...
     self.z = ""
```

If I receive a dict or JSON with extra fields or typos my Object is polluted

```
doc = {
 "a" : "hello",
 "extrafields" : "not required"
}

myobj = MyClass(doc)
```

myobj is now polluted with extrafield

How can I construct my Object but make sure it's not polluted with the extra fields in the document that are not part of the class definition?

Comment: `fields` is a `dict`, you can do with it everything you could do with any other `dict`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just pass the doc as input.

```
Class Myclass:
  def _init__(self, doc)
     self.a = doc['a'] if 'a' in doc else None
     self.b = doc['b'] if 'b' in doc else None
     ...
     self.z = doc['z'] if 'z' in doc else None
```